# Who is credited for my anonymous edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I rushed to edit an [answer](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/12149) without logging in.

I have logged in only after seeing the message

> Thanks for your edit! This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

Will the answer appear anonymous or in with my user?
I still have that window open.

Comment: The edit is still in the queue. Maybe i can reject it so you can repost?

Comment: yes, rejecting it is fine, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It appears as anonymous; that's how you submitted it.

> [image: suggested edit example]

As such, it can't be later credited to another account and is given to the Anonymous user account.

Comment: If it's accepted the edit shows as having been made by [Community ♦](http://superuser.com/users/-1/community) in the post history.